# How to get data from async functions in react components, react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to redux and react. I have React container and component which gets data from the api request call. My question in basically, what is the best way to handle asyc functons of redux in react. I need help to get the data in react component.

Container.js: (incomplete, here I need help)

```
class Container extends React.Component {

  state = {
    userList: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadUserDetails();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
       <Component userList={this.state.userList}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userList: state.auth.userList
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
  loadUserDetails
}, dispatch);

export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Container));
```

Componet.js: (Pure component, here I need to render the data)

```
class Component extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component">
       {this.props.userList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

modules/auth/index.js

```
export const loadUserDetails = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.LOAD_USER_REQUEST
    });
    request.get('/api/v1/auth', dispatch)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      if (data.success) {
        dispatch({
          type: types.LOAD_USER_SUCCESS
      payload: data.data
        });
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: types.LOAD_USER_FAILURE,
          payload: data.message
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: types.LOAD_USER_FAILURE,
        payload: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'
      });
    });
  };
};
```

modules/auth/actions.js:

```
export const LOAD_USER_REQUEST = 'auth/LOAD_USER_REQUEST';
export const LOAD_USER_SUCCESS = 'auth/LOAD_USER_SUCCESS';
export const LOAD_USER_FAILURE = 'auth/LOAD_USER_FAILURE';
```

modules/auth/reducers.js:

```
state ={
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    userList: null
}


case types.LOAD_USER_REQUEST: 
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
    loading: true
      });
    case types.LOAD_USER_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
    loading: false,
        userList: payload,
      });
    case types.LOAD_USER_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
    loading: flase,
    error: payload
      });
```

I actually need help to get the userList in Container and pass it to the Component. because it's an asyc function I am not able to get the data in Container before Component renders. How to handle such situations?

As I am passing `userList` in Child component, for the first time I don't have the  `userList` data. So my problem is with the cycles of Reactjs, Where should I call `loadUserList` ? In componentDidMount? Or componentDidUpdate? If so, how can I get the data?

I am not able to render the `userList` it's value is `null` when the Component mounts. How to solve this?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878448/6219957

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait until all of the properties of received synchronous array are set in React-Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877971/how-to-wait-until-all-of-the-properties-of-received-synchronous-array-are-set-in)

Comment: No..no, My problem is not in redux, but in react. I have set the thunk, and store everything. Where I need to call the ```loadUserDetails``` to get the ```userList```  ? In ```compoentDidMount```? Or ```componentDidUpdate``` ?  If so, how?

Comment: Oh well, you have to call the loadUserDetails as soon as the component is mounted (componentDidMount). How? The way you did it. Is the way you've done it not working? If so, are there any errors?

Comment: Sure.. edited the question. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `{this.props.userList}`, have you tried `{this.props.userList.length > 0 && this.props.userList}`

Comment: Also, I'd suggest that you dont call your component `Component` as this might and mostly prolly will collide with React's named export `Component`

Comment: I tried that. But again it renders, nothing. Can I make use of ```loader``` state ?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't named as Component.

Comment: sorry, pardon me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172377/discussion-between-akhila-hegde-and-brandnew).

Answer (score 0):

a good option is to make use of redux-saga, easy and simple to implement:

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga